# How to apply a function in data.table by group then output the result in the new column?

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data set looks like following:

```
Date<-rep(seq(as.Date("2000/1/1"), as.Date("2001/1/1"), by = "quarter"),2)
Name<-c(rep("a",5),rep("b",5))
Return<-rnorm(10,0,0.1)
dt<-data.table(Date,Name,Return)
```

and the sample is in the following form:

```
    Date        Name   Return
 1: 2000-01-01    a  0.049675002
 2: 2000-04-01    a -0.017131607
 3: 2000-07-01    a  0.157891524
 4: 2000-10-01    a  0.112921428
 5: 2001-01-01    a  0.190409895
 6: 2000-01-01    b  0.001505096
 7: 2000-04-01    b -0.135364485
 8: 2000-07-01    b  0.050353871
 9: 2000-10-01    b  0.145750019
10: 2001-01-01    b  0.025039778
```

The problem is the return in datatable is not what I am looking for. The data I want to use should be in the form of price in stead of return. The question assume the price before the first period in the data is 100, and by apply function: **P**t=**P**t-1*(1+**R**t)  (The t and t-1 is subscripts in this equation) I could generate a new column of price. so I hope I could get something like the following:

```
    Date      Name  Return       Price
1   01/01/2000  a   0.049675002  104.9675002
2   01/04/2000  a   -0.017131607 103.1692383
3   01/07/2000  a   0.157891524  119.4587865
4   01/10/2000  a   0.112921428  132.9482432
5   01/01/2001  a   0.190409895  158.2629043
6   01/01/2000  b   0.001505096  100.1505096
7   01/04/2000  b   -0.135364485 86.59368745
8   01/07/2000  b   0.050353871  90.95401482
9   01/10/2000  b   0.145750019  104.2105642
10  01/01/2001  b   0.025039778  106.8199736
```

To be specific, the difficulties are:

1. I need apply this within the group with different names, the real data have about 160 different names. Under each name, I need to assume the starting price to P0 =100(we don't need this 100 in the price series.
2. The data length under each name is actually different, some of them have 100 observation while other might just have 85, there is no pattern in the data length under each name.
3. How to use the price from the last period when write the formula to calculate the current price? I don't find the way refer back to previous observation as simply do Price[-1] doesn't work.

Thank you very much for your time and help in advance!!!

Comment: Please use `set.seed` in order to make your problem reproducible and make it easier for us to match your desired output

Comment: Sorry David, I will be careful next time. Thank you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
DT[,Price:=100*cumprod(1+Return),by=Name]
#           Date Name       Return     Price
#  1: 2000-01-01    a  0.049675002 104.96750
#  2: 2000-04-01    a -0.017131607 103.16924
#  3: 2000-07-01    a  0.157891524 119.45879
#  4: 2000-10-01    a  0.112921428 132.94824
#  5: 2001-01-01    a  0.190409895 158.26290
#  6: 2000-01-01    b  0.001505096 100.15051
#  7: 2000-04-01    b -0.135364485  86.59369
#  8: 2000-07-01    b  0.050353871  90.95401
#  9: 2000-10-01    b  0.145750019 104.21056
# 10: 2001-01-01    b  0.025039778 106.81997
```